# asp.net boolean search string function

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, boolean-logic

Any of you know how to do boolean search engine in asp.net c# application, i have to search the given string (search the string using boolean logic AND,OR,NOT) in my asp.net application(only **aspx** and **html** files)...

please help me...

Comment: dont know how to split the search string according to the boolean logic..

Comment: pardon me for lack of knowledge.. but what does that mean ?

Comment: here u can see the boolean logic.. http://www.usg.edu/galileo/skills/unit04/primer04_08.phtml

Comment: @Vasagam If I understand your question correctly, you need to do an **advanced search** in the files of your c# application. You don't need to do this problematically, or do this within the data of your app, but **within your source code**. Please edit you question to clarify what you search, where you search it and why you need to search it because, as you see from the answers you get, it's not easy to understand right now.

Comment: @DavRob60: Yes, a clarification would be useful. Since he wrote "how to do boolean search **engine**", I figured he needed to do it in code (i.e. implement an engine).

Answer (score 2):

Basically, you need to parse the input (split the string, then iterate through the words) and construct a tree. Since the operators (AND, OR, ...) are *between* the keywords, you need an *infix parser*.

You can either write one yourself (the keyword "infix parser" should return enough Google results to get you started -- note that this is not a trivial task if you don't have at least some computer science background) or use a tool such as [ANTLR](http://www.antlr.org/), which is supposed to make writing parsers easy.

Here's a related question; I'm not sure if the answer is applicable to your case, though:

- [Are there any good tutorials that describe how to use ANTLR to parse boolean search strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1209005)

Answer (score 0):

In the find and replace window :<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>

- check "use" and select "regular expression"

> This triangular button next to the Find what field becomes available when the Use check box is selected in Find options. Click this button to display a list of wildcards or regular expressions, depending upon the Use option selected. Choosing any item from this list adds it into the Find what string. 
>    - [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dechx2tz%28VS.80%29.aspx)

So you will have to build your "boolean logic search" using [Regular expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev10.query?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28VS.REGULAREXPRESSIONBUILDER%29;k%28TargetFrameworkMoniker-%22.NETFRAMEWORK,VERSION=V3.5%22%29&rd=true) (And now [you have 2 problems](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/20842#20842))

Also set the Look at these files types: to `*.html;*.aspx;`
and Look in `Entire Solution`

[image]

Comment: is there any predefined function or tool for boolean search engine in asp.net..?

Comment: No, In Visual studio, the thing that is the nearest of your needs is regular expression. Meanwhile you may use a external program.